# MediaPlayer cannot play file names without an extension

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I try to play a **local file** having no file extension the component `System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement` fails with a FileNotFoundException saying **"Media file download failed.":null**. The inner exception is a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` with HResult 0xC00D0FEA.

I tried the Uri I assigned to `MediaPlayer.Source` with `WebClient.DownloadData(Uri)` and there were no problems with neither the uri nor the returned data.

Update:
While I first concentrated on why `new Uri(@"c:\temp\filename.")` just becomes `file:///c:/temp/filename` (swallowing the trailing dot) after finally renaming the file to "filename.data" still the very same exception is thrown. I assume that WPF -- which is using Media Foundation, which is newest technology -- uses file name extensions instead of just parsing file data. *facepalm*

Comment: Try adding "." to the end of the filename you give to the `MediaElement` control.

Comment: @PeterRitchie this doesn't change anything. In fact the Uri constructor against "\\server\share\dir\filenamewithoutextension." just ignores/kills the trailing dot (.net 4.5.2)

Comment: the error suggests it is adding an extension when it tries to download (or, the file without an extension is actually not at the URI).  If you know the type of the media file, try renaming it or copying it to a path with the appropriate extension and try using that new URI.

Comment: @springy76, have you tried my solution "adding MIME type", this might help!

Comment: Please look close: I'm talking about a local file system file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Media Player uses DirectShow filters to load the file.
If there is no extension it does not know which filter to use.

The same error appears if you try and open a stream without a registered scheme.

The schemes are saved in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Player\Schemes`.

By adding a scheme here it can be opened in the MediaPlayer (as long as the correct filters have been opened)

Comment: The same app is already using native DirectShow for rendering bitmap frames to memory and I can tell you that DirectShow doesn't care about file extensions (I`m only working with Streams there). WPF's "MediaPlayer" uses Media Foundation which is a parallel framework to DirectShow.