# Play video from UDP/RTSP using MediaElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player

Is it possible to play videos streamed from UDP/RTSP using WPF's MediaElement control? During my testing, I have attempted to pass a URI containing a UDP stream to the MediaElement player, but when I launch my application, the media player is blank as though there is no media source. Here is my sample code:

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window 
{
    public MainWindow() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        VideoMediaElement.Source = new Uri("udp:\\\\@12.3.4.567:890");
        VideoMediaElement.Play();
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <MediaElement Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="VideoMediaElement" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
</Grid>
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing here? I have tested this setup using a video that is stored on my file system, and it plays with no problems - it's just the streaming that doesn't want to work.

If this is not possible using MediaElement, I am open to suggestions for controls that I can use instead. However, I need a control that is purely WPF and does not rely on any WinForms interop. Any suggestions are appreciated.

UPDATE: After creating a handler for the "MediaFailed" event, I was able to receive this error: "Media file download failed" with an inner exception of System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException with HResult 0xC00D0FEA. I referenced this: [MediaPlayer cannot play file names without an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126097/mediaplayer-cannot-play-file-names-without-an-extension) and attempted to make some changes to the registry, but they don't seem to be fixing the problem. Again, any suggestions are appreciated. I'll continue to update this thread as I get more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After A LOT of research, it seems that what I am attempting to do may not be possible. The WPF MediaElement control (and Windows Media Player) appear to support playing videos over a network, but not from a stream. See the following thread on MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e90b7e73-62b2-40b2-a725-4b60e02d65a1/play-video-stream-in-wpf?forum=wpf

I'm still on the lookout for a WPF control that will play video from a stream, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: You can create http proxy server on C#. Set url on mediaelement and wait for request on C# client. Send video stream as a response stream. It will work.

Comment: any updates on this? i am in the exact same boat, albiet a few years late.

Answer (score 4):

See [FFME](https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement), an almost drop-in replacement for MediaElement, based on FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but recently found that the ffmediaelement (Install-Package FFME.Windows) worked fine for MISB streams. Only used for a day so far, only issue is that needed to reset the control if the streaming source looped back to the start of the video file. Requires separate download of FFMPEG DLLs.

https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement